# Solving linear regression equation for a sparse matrix

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn, linear-regression

I'd like to solve a multivariate linear regression equation for vector **X** with *m* elements while I have *n* observations, **Y**. If I assume the measurements have *Gaussian random errors*. How can I solve this problem using python? My problem looks like this:

[image]

A simple example of **W** when *m=5*, is given as follows:

[image]

P.S. I would like to consider the effect of errors and precisely I want to measure the standard deviation of errors.

Comment: @kmario23 I have **W** and **Y** and I want to estimate **X** and error.

Comment: One approach could be to find pseudo-inverse of `W` and multiply the equation.

Comment: @kmario23 it is in the case I consider there are no measurement uncertainties

Comment: I'd be concerned about the numerical stability issues of the [pseudo-inverse, normal equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_least_squares_(mathematics)#Inverting_the_matrix_of_the_normal_equations) approach. Consider scipy's [sparse least squares iterative solver](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.linalg.lsqr.html#scipy.sparse.linalg.lsqr) instead.

Comment: @ChesterVonWinchester There isn't any big difference between the result of what you suggested and the answer which is posted here even if damp>0 ..

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this

```
def myreg(W, Y):
    from numpy.linalg import pinv
    m, n = Y.shape
    k = W.shape[1]
    X = pinv(W.T.dot(W)).dot(W.T).dot(Y)
    Y_hat = W.dot(X)
    Residuals = Y_hat - Y
    MSE = np.square(Residuals).sum(axis=0) / (m - 2)
    X_var = (MSE[:, None] * pinv(W.T.dot(W)).flatten()).reshape(n, k, k)
    Tstat = X / np.sqrt(X_var.diagonal(axis1=1, axis2=2)).T
    return X, Tstat
```

***demo***

```
W = np.array([
        [ 1, -1,  0,  0,  1],
        [ 0, -1,  1,  0,  0],
        [ 1,  0,  0,  1,  0],
        [ 0,  1, -1,  0,  1],
        [ 1, -1,  0,  0, -1],
    ])

Y = np.array([2, 4, 1, 5, 3])[:, None]

X, V = myreg(W, Y)
```